# How to display post pagination in wordpress (if possible without a plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress

My blog that runs on Wordpress has several pages of posts. I have the page navigation set up (so I have a link for "Older Entries" and "Newer Entries").

I was wondering if it's possible to do something like this:

1 | 2 | 3 | 4 ... 32 | Last Page

EDIT: Thanks to Adam, I replaced the wp_list_pages with the wp_link_pages function as follows:

```
            <?php $pageargs = array(
        'next_or_number'   => 'number'
        ); ?>
    <ul>
        <?php wp_link_pages( $pageargs ); ?> 
    </ul>
```

I also tried just the default:

```
<?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
```

However, it still doesn't work. I'm not getting post pagination. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: "Pages" in WordPress are actual content pages, not posts. I assume that by "post pages" you mean post pagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WordPress › WP-Paginate « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-paginate/) does that kind of pagination.

Comment: So I can't use wp_link_pages() built in function? why does it not work??

Comment: Looks like the WP function isn't sophisticated enough.

Answer (score 2):

I think [wp_list_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) deals with listing content pages, whereas what you're looking for is [wp_link_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages) which provides pagination.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey. Could you please take a look at my EDIT and see if you know how to fix things?

Answer (score -1):

You are searching a PageNavigation?

There are so many Scripts for this, the most used one is: [WP-PageNavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/)

It is really easy to implement. You only have to add:

```
 <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
```

this to your Template File(s).